# python code to read and write after each write it read the whole file than increment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I have a python code to read some data from the serial port of the Artix-7 FPGA board it reads well. Then After read it suppose to write some data that is 9-digit hexadecimal number to the port it did well but the problem is after each write is read all the text file first then increment and the size of my text file is too big its about 1348065 lines .

here is the code please guide someone.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
    import serial, time
    from addresstable import *
    import binascii
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB1"
    ser.baudrate = 38400
    ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS 
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE 
    ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE              
    ser.xonxoff = False    
    ser.rtscts = False    
    ser.dsrdtr = False  
    number_address = 1341602
    number_char = 9  
    timeout=1
    #f=open('lut.txt','r')

    try: 
        ser.open()
        except Exception, e:
        print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
        exit()

    if ser.isOpen():

        try:
             ser.flushInput()
             ser.flushOutput()
    # reading        
             max_packet = 20
             lines = 0
             while True:
               byteData = ser.read_until('\r',max_packet)
               newdata=str(byteData)
               print newdata.strip()

               ser.write('I')
               time.sleep(0.01)
    # writing
               with open('adder-sem-address-sen0.txt', 'r') as f:
                for line in f.readlines():
                 #print line
                 ser.write('N')
                 time.sleep(0.01)
                 ser.write(' ')
                 time.sleep(0.01)
                 ser.write('C')
                 time.sleep(0.01)
                 for i in line:
                  newdata=i
                  ser.write(newdata)
                  time.sleep(0.01)

                time.sleep(1)



        except Exception, e1:
            print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)

    else:
        print "cannot open serial port "
```

My expected output is looks line

```
I>NC0000AABBF
I>NC0000AABBF
I>NC0000AABBA
```

and continue, it does same  but after each line read it first it red the whole text file than read the next line

Comment: Don't use this: `for line in f.readlines()`. That reads the entire file and returns a list of lines. Instead, iterate over the file, one line at a time: `for line in f`.

Comment: You have indentation errors. Can you fix those so we see what the nested code blocks really are?

Comment: It seems like you open and write the file many times within a `while True`. Is that the problem? BTW, following the standard 4 space indentation rule makes it easier for us to read the program. Keep with the look others expect!

Comment: Sorry for infection problem. The file should open at once than read the lines in the file one by one and send it to the port. The problem is before sending a line it read the whole file.

Comment: Anyone have any idea I have tried this f.read(). But it didn't work some problem is with the read it read data from the port and then start reading the whole file.